# Which of these sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

1. Upon learning about the incident, the agency launched an internal investigation to accurately determine the impacted customers.
2. Upon learning the incident, the agency launched an internal investigation to accurately determine the impacted customers.

Which one is correct? Or are both sentences okay?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Which do you think is correct, and why?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The 'about' is necessary in this sentence.  'Learn' only takes a direct object in certain cases such as school subjects/languages: "learn English", "learn maths", but not in this case.  (I couldn't tell you off the top of my head the definitive rules here, maybe someone else can).